# Web App Security Issues - VB or C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, security

Assume I write two web sites, one in C# and one in VB that perform the same actions and I put into place the same security on both sites.

Will the VB web site be less secure than the C# web site?

I believe there are no additional security issues with VB versus C#, however I would like to confirm that I am correct.

Comment: c# and VB are just programming languages. The underlying framework you use (eg ASP.NET) or MVC will be the same for both and so the security will be the same for both.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference.  They have (mostly) the same features and execute on the same virtual machine.  VB does disallow `unsafe`, but you can just as easily avoid this keyword in C#.

Answer (score 2):

No, there won't be a difference - both languages compile to the same bytecode anyway.

Of course this only applies if the code actually does the same - but from a language point of view there's no difference.

Comment: Is there stats to back up "you might find more bad VB developers than C# developers" or is that just an opinion? Just curious because although I have no love for VB it does feel unfair to state this explicitly...

Comment: Ahhhh... it wouldn't be a VB.NET vs. C# question without a cheap shot at VB.NET developers.